# Artifactory creating folders instead of deploying artifact

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory, jenkins-cli

I have a plugin forked from artifactory jenkins plugin which deploys artifacts to artifactory. It was working fine for sometime now when I hit a weird issue a couple of days ago : I deploy my artifact to a layout and the plugin deploys fine but at the leaf level of the layout instead of deploying the artifact it makes that as an empty folder.

I go into the logs and see the following:

```
 (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:273) - MKDir request to 'yum-snapshot-local:rhel5/i386/packages//-1.12.13-d.34.i386.rpm'
    2015-06-04 00:00:10,219 [http-bio-8081-exec-1339] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:279) - Directory 'yum-snapshot-local:rhel5/i386/packages//-1.12.13-d.34.i386.rpm' was created successfully.
    2015-06-04 00:00:11,326 [http-bio-8081-exec-1366] [INFO ] (o.a.r.r.c.BuildResource:286) - Adding build 'test #34'
    2015-06-04 00:00:11,550 [http-bio-8081-exec-1366] [INFO ] (o.a.r.r.c.BuildResource:303) - Added build 'test #34'
```

As you can see for some reason the plugin is making mkdir request instead of deploying and thats why creates empty directories but this just  a fork from 2.2.7 artifactory jenkins plugin.

I use the older version of the plugin and that seems to deploy fine, log shows :

```
2015-06-03 23:48:00,458 [http-bio-8081-exec-1339] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:479) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-
    local:djin/platforn/cande/FreeBSD/i386/packages/something/something-1.12.13-d.20.i386.rpm' Content-Length: 51
```

Any reason why it should suddenly make mkdir rquest? Also where can I find this "o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl" file ?

EDIT 1.0

much thanks, looks like the issue is here :

```
private void adjustResponseAndUpload(ArtifactoryRequest request, ArtifactoryResponse response,
            LocalRepo targetRepository) throws IOException {
        if (processOriginatedExternally(response)) {
            response = new DelayedHttpResponse((HttpArtifactoryResponse) response);
        }
        try {
            if (request.isDirectoryRequest()) {
                createDirectory(request, response);
            } else if (request.isChecksum()) {
                validateAndUploadChecksum(request, response, targetRepository);
            } else if (NamingUtils.isMetadata(request.getPath())) {
                response.sendError(SC_CONFLICT, "Old metadata notation is not supported anymore: " +
                        request.getRepoPath(), log);
            } else {
                uploadArtifact(request, response, targetRepository);
            }
```

if (request.isDirectoryRequest()) is returning true for some reason, hence its processing it as a folder, but for what good reason ?

Comment: Artifactory sources are available at http://subversion.jfrog.org/artifactory/public/trunk/

Comment: The class you are looking for is org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl

Comment: @drorb thanks- look up my edit.

Comment: you should find out what is the actual request sent from the plugin to Artifactory. User a proxy/HTTP sniffer to record the request.

Comment: I faced the same problem, raised an issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32869

Comment: UPDATE: All works fine if I don't use "Deployment properties" option.